# what is xcode 3.2.3 analyzer version?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

HI,

I am using Xcode3.2.3. i want to know that what is the build version of clang-analyzer that Xcode is using ???

the current clang-analyzer build version is 247.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static analysis is done by running `/Developer/usr/bin/clang` with the `--analyze` flag set.  So you can pop open Terminal and run `/Developer/usr/bin/clang --version`.

On my machine, this prints:

```
Mephistopheles:bin dave$ clang --version
Apple clang version 1.5 (tags/Apple/clang-60)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: As an additional note to Dave's excellent answer, if you have multiple versions of xcode installed, you can ensure you use your default version of clang with xcode-select: \`xcode-select -print-path\`/usr/bin/clang --version